# Find Force from Moment Vector, Given Radius and Unit Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse, moment-problem

Given a known Moment ($\vec{M}$), distance ($\vec{r}$), and unit vector $\hat{f}$  of force ($\vec{F}$), is it possible to find the resultant magnitude of force (using the formulation of the cross product)? Here the unit vector of force $\hat{f}$, $\vec{r}$, and $\vec{M}$ are all known.

I've been trying to think through using a [Skew-Symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) but I'm not sure how to bound the solutions from:

$\vec{M} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}\\$

$\vec{M} = [\vec{r}]_{x} \vec{F}\\$

$\vec{F} = [\vec{r}]^{-1}_{x} \vec{M}$

with a given unit vector $\hat{r}$

Is this even possible?

Comment: I wasn't as clear - will correct above:

$\hat{f}$ is a unit vector of $\vec{F}$  (known)

$\hat{r}$ is a unit vector of $\vec{r}$  ($\vec{r}$ is known, so $\hat{r}$ can be derived)

Could you do something like:

$\vec{M} = |\vec{r}||\vec{F}|(\hat{r} \times \hat{f})$

or, 

$|\vec{F}| = \frac{\vec{M}}{|\vec{r}|(\hat{r} \times \hat{f})}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you won't get an equation of the type $\vec F=k\vec M$ as that would imply $\vec F,\vec M$ are parallel while the original equation implies they are orthogonal.

Using $\vec F=|\vec F|\hat f$ we get $\vec M=|\vec F|(\vec r\times \hat f)$ so you can find $|\vec F|$ by taking the ratio of the $x$ components $[\vec M]_x$ and $[\vec r\times\hat f]_x$ (or the $y/z$ components) or the ratio of the magnitudes $|\vec M|$ and $|\vec r\times\hat f|$.

I am not sure what you want to do with a skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: Ah, I guess if we just look at the magnitude of force here then it becomes somewhat trivial (using the corrected notation above). So from $\vec{M} = vec{r} \times \vec{F} $  we can form $|\vec{M}| = |\vec{r} \times \hat{f}| |F|$ or $|\vec{F}| = \frac{|M|}{|\vec{r} \times \hat{f}|} $

correct?

Comment: @KrishnaSoni Yes, that is correct.